# How to multiple a string by the number specified in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I has a dataframe like the following, and then need to add a column whose value is " " * start_time + "*" * (end_time - start_time + 1), so the first row will have a value like ' **'(1 space, 2 stars), and the second row will have value '  ****' (2 space and 4 stars), how to do that?

```
start_time end_time
 1           2
 2           5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
df['out'] = [' '*s+'*'*(e-s+1) for s,e in zip(df['start_time'], df['end_time'])]
```

Or a multiplication:

```
df['out'] = (df.eval('sub=end_time-start_time+1')[['start_time', 'sub']]
               .mul({'start_time': ' ', 'sub': '*'}).agg(''.join, axis=1)
            )
```

Output:

```
   start_time  end_time     out
0           1         2      **
1           2         5    ****
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
# DataFrame is named as df
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: ' ' * row['start_time'] + '*' * (row['end_time'] - row['start_time'] + 1), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**